How to implement OR Tools Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows?
I ran the official code that Google has in its documentation.
It considers that there are 4 vehicles, Time Windows for all location, allow waiting time and maximum time per vehicle. When I copy and paste it it run perfectly.
But, I need it with adjustments:

vehicles: 1 or 2
Time Windows: just for some location, sometimes 1 or 2 locations.
allow waiting time: don't know how measure this (minutes or hours)
maximum time per vehicle: don't know how measure this (minutes or hours) and how to interpret this, is the max time for the vehicle in the whole route or what?

Official Code:
"""Vehicles Routing Problem (VRP) with Time Windows."""
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp


def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data["time_matrix"] = [
        [0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3, 6, 2, 3, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 9, 7],
        [6, 0, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4, 8, 8, 13, 7, 5, 8, 12, 10, 14],
        [9, 8, 0, 11, 10, 6, 3, 9, 5, 8, 4, 15, 14, 13, 9, 18, 9],
        [8, 3, 11, 0, 1, 7, 10, 6, 10, 10, 14, 6, 7, 9, 14, 6, 16],
        [7, 2, 10, 1, 0, 6, 9, 4, 8, 9, 13, 4, 6, 8, 12, 8, 14],
        [3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 7, 9, 7, 7, 6, 12, 8],
        [6, 8, 3, 10, 9, 2, 0, 6, 2, 5, 4, 12, 10, 10, 6, 15, 5],
        [2, 4, 9, 6, 4, 3, 6, 0, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 10],
        [3, 8, 5, 10, 8, 2, 2, 4, 0, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 3, 13, 6],
        [2, 8, 8, 10, 9, 2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 5],
        [6, 13, 4, 14, 13, 7, 4, 8, 4, 4, 0, 10, 9, 8, 4, 13, 4],
        [6, 7, 15, 6, 4, 9, 12, 5, 9, 6, 10, 0, 1, 3, 7, 3, 10],
        [4, 5, 14, 7, 6, 7, 10, 4, 8, 5, 9, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 8],
        [4, 8, 13, 9, 8, 7, 10, 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6],
        [5, 12, 9, 14, 12, 6, 6, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 9, 2],
        [9, 10, 18, 6, 8, 12, 15, 8, 13, 9, 13, 3, 4, 5, 9, 0, 9],
        [7, 14, 9, 16, 14, 8, 5, 10, 6, 5, 4, 10, 8, 6, 2, 9, 0],
    ]
    data["time_windows"] = [
        (0, 5),  # depot
        (7, 12),  # 1
        (10, 15),  # 2
        (16, 18),  # 3
        (10, 13),  # 4
        (0, 5),  # 5
        (5, 10),  # 6
        (0, 4),  # 7
        (5, 10),  # 8
        (0, 3),  # 9
        (10, 16),  # 10
        (10, 15),  # 11
        (0, 5),  # 12
        (5, 10),  # 13
        (7, 8),  # 14
        (10, 15),  # 15
        (11, 15),  # 16
    ]
    data["num_vehicles"] = 4
    data["depot"] = 0
    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f"Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}")
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("Time")
    total_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = f"Route for vehicle {vehicle_id}:\n"
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += (
                f"{manager.IndexToNode(index)}"
                f" Time({solution.Min(time_var)},{solution.Max(time_var)})"
                " -> "
            )
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += (
            f"{manager.IndexToNode(index)}"
            f" Time({solution.Min(time_var)},{solution.Max(time_var)})\n"
        )
        plan_output += f"Time of the route: {solution.Min(time_var)}min\n"
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += solution.Min(time_var)
    print(f"Total time of all routes: {total_time}min")


def main():
    """Solve the VRP with time windows."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data["time_matrix"]), data["num_vehicles"], data["depot"]
    )

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data["time_matrix"][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Time Windows constraint.
    time = "Time"
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        30,  # allow waiting time
        30,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time,
    )
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
    # Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data["time_windows"]):
        if location_idx == data["depot"]:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
    depot_idx = data["depot"]
    for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
            data["time_windows"][depot_idx][0], data["time_windows"][depot_idx][1]
        )

    # Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
    for i in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i))
        )
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

My modifications:
(Only will paste the modifications I did)
Modifications:
data["time_windows"] = [
        (0, 15),  # depot
        (0, 15),  # 1
        (0, 15),  # 2
        (0, 15),  # 3
        (0, 15),  # 4
        (0, 15),  # 5
        (0, 15),  # 6
        (0, 15),  # 7
        (0, 15),  # 8
        (0, 15),  # 9
        (0, 15),  # 10
        (0, 15),  # 11
        (0, 15),  # 12
        (5, 8),  # 13
        (0, 15),  # 14
        (0, 15),  # 15
        (0, 15),  # 16
    ]
    data["num_vehicles"] = 1

But it returns nothing. I understand that there is no solution.
Reasons of modification: I put (0,15) because I think that in this way the window will be from hour 0 to hour 15, I mean all day, I mean there is no specific time window for those locations.
How can I modify it correctly to my needs?

I recommend trying to understand what that code is doing and why it's doing it like that before changing it. Your time-windows are expressed in abstract discrete time ticks, not hours. If you talk about 15 hours irt. TWs (aka "visit me until"), then depot -> 2 costs 9 ticks = hours. 2 -> 3 costs another 11 ticks= hours . We already accumulated 20 ticks = hours only visiting 2 nodes!... Or differently: With a single vehicle, there is no path in that matrix not accumulating way too many ticks=hours. There is no solution! Changing TW.end from 15 to 150 or 1500 would repair that.

But your code also has a max accumulated travel-time per vehicle 30,  # maximum time per vehicle which is another infeasibility-reason you need to touch when removing vehicles here. In general:: you should assume that carefully crafted examples in discrete-optimization are rather tight aka easily made infeasible when changing things! (or else those example are not interesting / showing any interesting solver-behaviour at all; except for dual-optimality maybe)

Thanks @sascha, that word was key,"accumulated", Do you know how to interpret the "allow waiting time"?

The function-docstring explains it: AddDimension(int evaluator_index, int64_t slack_max, ...); -> Docstring. [...]Quantities at a node are represented by "cumul" variables and the increase or decrease of quantities between nodes are represented by "transit" variables. These variables are linked as follows: if j == next(i), cumul(j) = cumul(i) + transit(i, j) + slack(i) where slack is a positive slack variable (can represent waiting times for a time dimension).
